# Accessing code in Swift 3 Error

Tags: swift, swift3

New in Xcode 8 beta 4, `NSError` is bridged to the Swift `Error` protocol type. This affects StoreKit when dealing with failed `SKPaymentTransaction`s. You ought to check to be sure the error didn't occur because the transaction was cancelled to know whether or not to show an error message to the user. You do this by examining the error's `code`. But with `Error` instead of `NSError`, there is no `code` defined. I haven't been able to figure out how to properly get the error code from `Error`.

This worked in the previous version of Swift 3:

```
func failedTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    if let transactionError = transaction.error {
        if transactionError.code != SKErrorCode.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
            //show error to user
        }
     }
     ...
}
```

Now that `error` is an `Error` not `NSError`, `code` is not a member.

Comment: Try `if (transaction.error as NSError).code != SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled {`

Comment: That works, just casting it as an `NSError`, thanks @LeoDabus

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Casting to `SKError` seems to be working for me in xCode 8 and Swift 3...

```
    guard let error = transaction.error as? SKError else {return}
    switch error.code {  // https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skerror.code
    case .unknown: break
    case .paymentCancelled: break
    case .clientInvalid: break
    case .paymentInvalid: break
    case .paymentNotAllowed: break
    case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed: break
    case .cloudServicePermissionDenied: break
    case .storeProductNotAvailable: break
    }
```

No need for `rawValue`.

Comment: Updating the correct answer to this one as it is the most correct. Much preferred to do this instead of casting to `NSError`. Confirmed it works.

Comment: Ain't that great? I have the very same problem but in ALAssets. But there does not seem to be an SKError equivalent in there

Comment: @Joey Apple had removed SKError from the iOS 11 public API on Xcode 9 betas 1 and 2. This was a bug that has been fixed on Xcode 9 beta 3. Now will have to use "SwiftyStoreKit"!

Answer (score 142):

Another option to access code and domain properties in Swift 3 Error types is extending it as follow:

```
extension Error {
    var code: Int { return (self as NSError).code }
    var domain: String { return (self as NSError).domain }
}
```

Comment: Check the answer of @murray-sagal, it is better to use the newly provided SKError, instead of switching back to Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 57):

Now in Xcode 8 and swift 3 the conditional cast is always succeeds, so you need do following:

```
let code = (error as NSError).code
```

and check the `code` for your needs. Hope this helps

Answer (score 11):

This is correct (Apple's own tests use this approach):

```
if error._code == SKError.code.paymentCancelled.rawValue { ... }
```

On the other hand, casting to NSError will probably be deprecated soon:

```
let code = (error as NSError).code // CODE SMELL!!
if code == SKError.code.paymentCancelled.rawValue { ... }
```

Comment: Is there a link to the approach used by Apples own tests?

Comment: Well, @AndrewPaulSimmons there wasn't a nice clean link but if you check out Apple's Git repo for Swift and then search for "_code", you can see all their own tests where they deal with the Error object in that way.  Check it out: https://github.com/apple/swift/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=_code

Comment: You consider casting to the correct class a code smell, but externally accessing underscored members is fine? Granted you should be accessing `.code` in an `if let` or a `guard let`, not just blindly assuming the cast worked.

Comment: You're right, @devios1. "Code smell" was a dumb way to put it.

Comment: 1. The `Error` protocol doesn't have a `_code` member, thus this code would fail to compile; 2. Casting to `NSError` is still permitted, 6 years later.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> error._code == NSURLErrorCancelled

to match the error code.

Comment: where did you find this way...? this is working ! but I wanna know the place which you got to know.

Comment: I just explore the Error protocol in Xcode where did found that one.

Comment: I didn't get. Could you please explain a bit. In Error protocol definition i didn't find even one word for Error._code.

Comment: The `Error` protocol has no requirements, thus the compiler should not allow you to call anything on a reference to just `Error`. Your code must've been different if it allowed you to use `_error`.

Answer (score 0):

A lot is changing. Here's update for Xcode 11.

`if let skError = transaction.error as? SKError, skError.code == .paymentCancelled {
    print("Cancelled")
}`

Comment: This is repeating the solution given [3 years before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273317), of casting to `SKError` and accessing the code afterwards.