# "switch(error!.code)" in canEvaluatePolicy function does not exist in Swift 3 (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, error-code, touch-id

I'm converting below code to Swift 3.

```
 if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error:nil) {

  // 2.
  context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
    localizedReason: "Logging in with Touch ID",
    reply: { (success : Bool, error : NSError? ) -> Void in

      // 3.
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if success {
          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dismissLogin", sender: self)
        }

        if error != nil {

          var message : NSString
          var showAlert : Bool

          // 4.
          switch(error!.code) {
```

Step 4 does not work anymore on Xcode 8, Swift 3. So I could not do the following cases:

```
switch(error!.code) {
          case LAError.AuthenticationFailed.rawValue:
            message = "There was a problem verifying your identity."
            showAlert = true
            break;
```

Currently, it's seems there was no solution that I could find yet. Any suggestion, please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No solution yet? The first hit for `[swift3] error code` is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711269/accessing-code-in-swift-3-error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First change your reply closure of `evaluatePolicy` method, in Swift 3 it is `Error` not `NSError`.

```
reply: { (success : Bool, error : Error? ) -> Void in
```

Second, change performSegue with identifier like this.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "dismissLogin", sender: self)
```

In Swift 3 you need to convert `Error` object to `NSError` or use `_code` with `Error` instance instead of `code`.

```
switch((error! as NSError).code)
```

OR

```
switch(error!._code)
```

You need to also change you dispatch syntax like this.

```
Dispatch.async.main {
    //write code
}
```

Comment: The first option is working a charm, bro. You're the best. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: He should also use `if let error = error` instead of `if error != nil` and avoid force unwrap the error object.

Answer (score 2):

This actually got a lot easier

context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
    localizedReason: "Logging in with Touch ID",
    reply: { (success : Bool, error : Error? ) -> Void in

```
  // 3.
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if success {
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dismissLogin", sender: self)
    }

    if let error = error {

      var message : NSString
      var showAlert : Bool

      // 4.
      switch error {
          case LAError.userCancel:
              //do stuff
```

This is mostly from memory, but I think it is correct.