# Getting Error Code from CLLocationManager didFailWithError

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Prior to Swift 3 I could get the error code by accessing `error.code`  Now under Swift 3 it seems the only attribute of the Error object is a string based textual description.  How can we get the enum value of error in this case?

```
optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
             didFailWithError error: Error)
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38732481/6541007)?

Comment: Thanks for the find!