# NSURLErrorDomain error -999 using UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, image-uploading, nsurl, nsurlerrordomain

I have a `UIWebView` in my iPhone application where I am loading the website. Basically I am opening the mobile website in app. In website, there is `media upload` functionality/ When user tries to upload photo(within mobile site), I am facing error is :-

> NSURLErrorDomain error -999

The same web view(code) works fine with other URLs like www.apple.com and www.google.com.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlToLoad]];
        [webview loadRequest:request];
```

It doesnt seem to be a redirect issue. How to fix the error?

I am also getting the below warnings.

> WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
>       filterBlacklist =     (
>       );
>       filterWhitelist =     (
>       );
>       restrictWeb = 1;
>       useContentFilter = 0;
>       useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
>       whitelistEnabled = 0; }

Related error link:- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1727260?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793459/xcode-8-ios-10-starting-webfilter-logging-for-process

disable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable`

Comment: @Dhiru, By disabling the activity mode, only console warnings will omit only. Actual issue is `NSURLErrorDomain error 999` while uploading photo in `UIWebView`

Answer (score 3):

This one is for WKWebView and Swift.

-999 is caused by ErrorCancelled. This means: *another request is made before the previous request is completed.* You can check it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076142/4003420)

In my scenario, I am checking the error code, if it is -999 then I just return from a function like following

```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

   if error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
        return
    }

   //*** Your functionality ***
}
```

Note: Unlike NSError of Objective-C, 'code' property is not available with Swift Error. You handle it by creating enum as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732481/4003420).